# unable to get a background image to load with css

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

this is a frustrating one.. I'm trying to display 3 images via CSS and am only able to get 1 to work (which has left me pretty confused b/c I am using the same approach for all 3..).  I'm also using Rails, which may or may not make some sort of routing difference.  Here's what I've got:

views/audioplayer/show.html.erb:

footer_lodyas.png **does not** work..

```
<style type="text/css">
  html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  body { padding: 260px; background: #f2f2f2 url(footer_lodyas.png) no-repeat top center; }
  .audio-player { margin: 0 auto;}
</style>
```

app/assets/stylesheets/audioplayer.css.scss:

play-pause.png **does** work

mute-unmute.png **does not** work

```
.mejs-controls .mejs-play button,
.mejs-controls .mejs-pause button {
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  top: 35px;
  left: 135px;
  background: transparent url(play-pause.png) 0 0;
}

.mejs-controls .mejs-mute button,
.mejs-controls .mejs-unmute button {
  width: 14px;
  height: 12px;
  top: 70px;
  left: 140px;
  background: transparent url(mute-umute.png) 0 0;
}
```

All of these images live in the `app/assets/images/` directory.  The server log gives me the following errors:

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/footer_lodyas.png"):`

and

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/mute-umute.png"):`

Why is this happening if my play-pause.png image is rendering fine??  Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `asset-url` instead of only `url`.

Comment: maybe you need to specify full path. `"app/assets/images/footer_lodyas.png")` or  `"/assets/images/footer_lodyas.png")`

Comment: try to change the name of images mute-unmute.png to mute_unmute.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**asset-url**

You'll need to use [`asset-url`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass):

```
background: transparent asset-url("mute-umute.png") 0 0;
```

The reason is that whenever you use assets in the pipeline, Rails expects to *precompile* them at some point. The precompilation process [*fingerprints*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) the new assets (precompiled assets are placed into the `public/assets` folder).

In production, you'd expect to have your images called something like `mute-umute-09239923492394923492349.png`.

If you call `url` on these assets, they simply won't load. You have to use the `asset-url` helper to pull the direct URL (including any fingerprinted filename) to the view.

---

> `play-pause.png` image is rendering fine

The likely reason for this is either that this file is not precompiled, or you've got it in some place which Rails is able to find.

Without knowing more about your server setup, I can only speculate about it.

---

[**SASS**](http://sass-lang.com/)

Lastly, a personal recommendation is to use `sass` - it's a better version of `scss` (which you're using already):

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/audioplayer.sass
.mejs-controls 
   .mejs-play button,
   .mejs-pause button 
     width: 21px
     height: 21px
     top: 35px
     left: 135px
     background: transparent asset-url("play-pause.png") 0 0

   .mejs-mute button,
   .mejs-unmute button 
     width: 14px
     height: 12px
     top: 70px
     left: 140px
     background: transparent asset-url("mute-umute.png") 0 0
```

Comment: I've never actually used `scss`, I myself as a beginner (with good knowledge of CSS that is) jumped straight to `sass` as it seemed so much less to write for the same however I also learned that people who think that the transition to `sass` from regular CSS can be hard to overcome which is why `scss` was created to make it easier to slowly transition into using `sass` functions while being able to write the way you want to write. - Just my 2c and I 100% agree with the recommendation but one should only do so when he/she is ready ofcourse :)

Comment: Thank you so much!  That was all I needed to get things to work.  Newer to Rails and am still getting used to it's conventions.  I've played around with SASS before, doesn't seem that it would be too hard to pick up.